# Print Unique Values while using Do-While loop

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a file named `textfile.txt` like below:

```
a 1 xxx
b 1 yyy
c 2 zzz
d 2 aaa
e 3 bbb
f 3 ccc
```

I am trying to filter the second column with a unique values in that. I had below code:

```
while read LINE
  do
    compname=`echo ${LINE} | cut -d' ' -f2 | uniq`
        echo -e "${compname}"
    done < textfile.txt
```

It is displaying:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

But I am looking for an output like:

```
1
2
3
```

I tried another command also like : `echo ${LINE} | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -u | uniq`
still not expected output.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to loop, `sort -u` already processes the whole input.

```
cut -d' ' -f2 textfile.txt | sort -u
```

Maybe you wanted to get the output in the original order, showing the first occurrence only? You can use an associative array to remember which values have been already seen:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A seen
while read x ; do
    [[ ${seen[$x]} ]] || printf '%s\n' "$x"
    seen[$x]=1
done < <(cut -d' ' -f2 textfile.txt)
```

For the last occurrence only, change the last line to

```
done < <(cut -d' ' -f2 textfile.txt | tac) | tac
```

(i.e. the last occurrence is the first occurrence in the reversed order)

Comment: If the file is guaranteed to already have that column in the desired, sorted order you can just use `uniq` to save a little processing, but I prefer the `sort -u` as suggested here unless you're sure. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges: Yes, but the only way to be sure is to include `sort -u` ;-)

Comment: Yep! Better to do and not need than need and not do.

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output of the loop to `sort -u`. There's no need for `cut`; the `read` command can handle this type of splitting.

```
while read -r _ compname _;  do
  echo "$compname"
done < textfile.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: I was originally going to use `uniq`, but @choroba had a good point about using `sort -u`, and I didn't update both places :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `sort -u` or `sort | uniq` after the `done` statement like this:

```
while read LINE;
  do
compname=$(echo ${LINE} | cut -d' ' -f2)
    echo "${compname}"
done < textfile.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: `uniq` in the while body doesn't make any sense - you're processing a single line at a time in there. Furthermore, looping over a file and running an operation on each line is an anti-pattern: have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for an excellent explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I removed the uniq command. I agree that the while loop is not necessary but the user explicitly asked for a solution containing it...

Comment: Ideally, you would show how to fix the approach in the question, and then show the one that's an order of magnitude better.

Comment: Likewise, here the variable and two echo statements seems like cruft to support the cruft of the unneeded loop, unless [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s point about wanting to keep the original *unsorted* order was needed...and he already handled that. :)